# In French, how do you say "How far along are you with X"?

Tags: expressions, anglais

In conversation with my friend, I said:

> Tu en es à combien de nouvelles recettes ?

I wonder if my phrasing conveys the idea of:

> **How far along are you with** (coming up with) new recipes?

How do French speakers commonly express the idea of "How far along are you with X"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the closest translation would be the French idiom **"Où en es-tu [...] ?"**

Examples:

> **Où en es-tu** avec les nouvelles recettes ?
>
> **Où en es-tu** dans la création de nouvelles recettes ?

More informal versions, used in spoken French:

> **Tu en es où** / **T'en es où** avec les nouvelles recettes ?
>
> **Tu en es où** / **T'en es où** dans la création de nouvelles recettes ?

Comment: Or more colloquially "Tu en es où avec/dans X ?"?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Precisely ;)

Comment: Hi. When you say "*Tu en es où avec **la trilogie Harry Potter** ?*", does it sound as if your interlocutor is writing the books himself? Instead of reading them?

Comment: For book series and TV shows, this idiom is widely used. "*Tu en es où **dans** la trilogie Harry Potter ?*" sounds as if you are reading the books, not writing them. Even though the very same sentence could be said in a conversation between a book writer and a friend asking him how far along he is with his writing. It really depends on the context.

Comment: Oh, I see. I wonder if "*Tu en es où **dans ton français** ?*" gets the job done? By the way, it'd be great if you frequented French SE. :)

Comment: To me, "*Tu en es où dans ton français ?*" would only make sense when used as a shortcut for "*Tu en es où dans ton/tes devoir(s) de français ?*" ("How far along are you with your french assignment(s)?"). Works with any other subject: "*Tu en es où dans tes maths?*", etc.

Comment: Can the phrase "Tu en es où dans ton français ?" ever be interpreted as "*Tu en es où dans **ton apprentissage du français** ?*"?

Comment: “*Tu en es où dans ton apprentissage du français*” is correct, but “*Tu en es où dans ton français*” just doesn’t sound right. As I said it only applies to homework, used otherwise it is strange and you’d be misunderstood.

Comment: Note that a "Bretonne" alternative is using "se rendre" instead of "être (à)", "Tu es rendu où...". But other may not understand it.